# How should I go about writing code that runs on a schedule that will run on multiple containers without race conditions?

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, scheduled-tasks

I'm wanting to write a service in nestjs that polls another service on a schedule. The problem is that if I have multiple containers how can I make sure one and only one container picks up the job? for example, say I need to obtain a session token from an upstream api on a schedule, but if I request multiple session ID's simultaneously previously requested session tokens are invalidated. Another example is say I want to poll some data source and post it into a sql table. I wouldn't want multiple containers to poll the same resource simultaneously. Is this an instance where I would want to use a cron job?

Comment: You could use a message queue like RabbitMQ and post a message there. Even if you have multiple containers consuming messages from the queue, only one will get it. If the event is time based, you could have a container post to the queue based on a cron job. Another option might be a Redis semaphore.

Comment: So we have a single container who's only job is to add jobs to the queue on a schedule while I can configure a library like bull to consume those events one container at a time?

Comment: You can do it however you prefer. The main thing is to only get one event on the queue.

Comment: If you are in fact running this on Kubernetes, you can use a native Kubernetes CronJob, which will launch only one container to do some task on a schedule.